# Check for a pair of elements in an array whose sum is equal to given sum

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I found this snippet from a Coding video by Google [here](https://youtu.be/XKu_SEDAykw?t=940)

```
bool HasPairWithSum(const vector<int> data, int sum){
  unordered_set<int> comp; //complements
    for(int value : data){
      if(comp.find(value) != comp.end)
        return true;
      comp.add(sum - value);
    }
    return false;
}
```

To check whether the pair of elements exists in an array whose sum is equal to given sum,

The following test cases works as explained in the video,

- {1, 2, 3, 9} Given Sum = 8
- {1, 2, 4, 4} Given Sum = 8

1.But, I'm still confused which of the following is correct

```
if(comp.find(value) != comp.end) // as in snippet or
if(comp.find(value) == comp.end) // this one
```

2.Also, how would this algorithm fit to,

- {1, 2, 4, 6} Given Sum = 8

Answer (score 0):

```
if(comp.find(value) != comp.end)
```

The above snippet is correct . What they are doing is that they are adding complementary value(ie if sum is 8 then 2 has complementary value 6)in comp and as soon as they find a complementary value they return true. Eg.

```
{1, 2, 4, 6} Given Sum = 8
```

7 is added 6 is added 4 is added and then now when they search for 6 it won't return comp.end and hence will enter if and return true.

Answer (score 0):

To run the snippet you have to do minor changes:-

- comp.end =====> comp.end()
- comp.add() =====> comp.insert()

Answer (score 0):

First, I realize this is an old question. But I recently watched the same video and wondered about the same thing (as I'm unfamiliar with c++). Here's what I learned after doing some digging.

---

I think that a good way to think about this is to consider `comp.end` - which should technically be `comp.end()` - to be akin to a **falsy** value*.

So if we allow that, we could walk through each iteration for the second test case and check if it makes sense.

For the input `{1, 2, 4, 4} Given Sum = 8`, the complements in the unordered set would be `c={7,6,4}` by the end of the iterations.

So in the for-each, the comparison `if(comp.find(value) != comp.end)` would look like this:

- `if(comp.find(1) != comp.end)` ==> `if(false != false)` ==> `if(false)` as `c={}`
- `if(comp.find(2) != comp.end)` ==> `if(false != false)` ==> `if(false)` as `c={7}`
- `if(comp.find(4) != comp.end)` ==> `if(false != false)` ==> `if(false)` as `c={7,6}`
- `if(comp.find(4) != comp.end)` ==> `if(true != false)` ==> `if(true)` as `c={7,6,4}`

For each comparison, you'll have `false != false` which will evaluate to `false` and not enter into the if statement where `true` gets returned, until you finally arrive at the last comparison, where `true != false` evaluates to `true`.

(Because the example that this question is based on was done on a whiteboard, I wrote a small [program](https://www.onlinegdb.com/bTwPNwa0z) that illustrates the same logic.)

---

*If you read some documentation on it, you'll see that the `end()` method returns an iterator *past-the-end* element which, to my understanding, seems to be outside of the set. (Whereas the `find()` method returns an iterator *at the* element if found and *past-the-end* if not found.)

In reality, there are no boolean values here, as they are actually iterator values that are being compared to one another (and something like `comp.find(7) == comp.find(6)` would evaluate to `false` although both values are in comp), but I think that booleans may be a simpler way to think about it (initially and for this specific example).